# Is it possible to make a search for only one page?

Tags: php, javascript, search

I have a glossary page: [link text](http://www.logicpkg.com/learn_glossary.htm)

I would like to know if it is possible to have a search field for the same page its on.  I only want to search the one page that has all the contents.

Is there a javascript, jquery or PHP script?

Comment: I'd have to say that Ignacio's solution is quite good! :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like the script found here: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm

It uses `window.find(string)` for non-IE browser and uses the Text Range object for IE.

Alternatively you can create something by iterating the DOM with javascript/jQuery.